# Can't edit permissions anymore

Tags: 7, users

I use the latest version of Drupal 7 and when I try changing some permissions and click to save, I get the following error:

> Notice : Undefined index: administer partner 6 dans user_role_grant_permissions() (ligne 3111 dans /home/name/www/modules/user/user.module).
>
> PDOException : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'module' cannot be null: UPDATE {role_permission} SET module=:db_update_placeholder_0 WHERE ( (rid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (permission = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ); Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] => [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 17 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => administer partner 6 ) dans user_role_grant_permissions() (ligne 3113 dans /home/name/www/modules/user/user.module).

*Administer partner x* is a special role I programmatically create when I add a new partner, using the following code.

```
$partner = entity_create('entity_partner',array(
    'type' => 'entity_partner',
    'id' => '',
    'title' => $partner_submission['title'],
    'admin' => system_name($partner_submission['admin']),
    'category' => $partner_submission['category'],
    'description' => $partner_submission['description'],
    'site' => $partner_submission['site'],
    'facebook' => $partner_submission['facebook'],
    'phone' => $partner_submission['phone'],
    'adresse' => $partner_submission['adresse'],
    'latitude' => $partner_submission['latitude'],
    'longitude' => $partner_submission['longitude'],
    'video' => $partner_submission['video'],
    'horaire' => $partner_submission['horaire'],
    'extradata01' => $partner_submission['extradata01']//machine name
));
field_attach_submit('entity_partner', $partner, $form, $form_state);
entity_save('entity_partner', $partner);

//create role
$new_role = 'admin_' . system_name($partner_submission['title']);
$roles = user_roles();
if (!in_array($new_role, $roles)) {
  $addRole = new stdClass();
  $addRole->name = $new_role;
  user_role_save($addRole); 
 $new_user_role = user_role_load_by_name($new_role);

// Add permission to this role.
$rid = intval($new_user_role->rid);
user_role_grant_permissions($rid, array('administer partner '.$partner->id, 'administer one partner'));

// Create partner administrator.
$user = array (
  'name' => system_name($partner_submission['admin']), 
  'pass' => system_name($partner_submission['admin_pass']),
  'mail' => system_name($partner_submission['admin_mail']), 
  'created' =>time(), 
  'login' =>0, 
  'access' =>0, 
  'status' => 1, 
  'language' => 'fr', 
  'init' => system_name($partner_submission['admin']), 
  'roles' => array (
     $rid => true, 
  ),
  'field_partner_destinataire' => array(
    'und' => array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => $partner->id)))
  );
  $account = user_save('', $user);

  // Add uid_admin.
  $partner->uid_admin = $account->uid;
  entity_save('entity_partner', $partner);
}
```

In my hook permission, I create all of them and it seems to work fine too.

```
$entities = entity_load('entity_partner');
//one secific perm per partner
foreach($entities as $entity){
    $items['administer partner '.$entity->id] = array(
        'title' => t('Administrer '.$entity->title),
        'restrict access' => TRUE,
    );
}
```

The code seems to work very fine, as roles are added to the user account and access work properly; the bug occur only when I try to change something on permissions with the admin panel.

I found some similar issues, but they are always old issues already fixed in core.

A workaround could be to manually edit the database, but I really want to avoid this.

---

This patch fix my problem, for the moment

https://www.drupal.org/node/737816#comment-6978566

But I don't know to make a patch persistent to an update

Comment: Check it: https://www.drupal.org/node/1249952

Comment: Already checked and not really help me